# CSS: Height 100% is not behaves as 100% even through parents 100%

Tags: html, css

I've been working on page for my client and I want to have background image on body (in fiddle there is black color instead of image) and content wrapper with width of 1200px (or so) and height of 100% of the page with white color background.

The problem is, that even though I have all parental elements set to have height 100%, the background is not 100% height. It's acting weird and I've tried to rewrite for 4th time without success. I don't know what is wrong. Could you please give me a hint, tip or solution. Thanks!

```
html, body {
                background: url('./images/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 14px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
}

.container {
                width: 1200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 100%;
                min-width: 1200px; 
                background-color: white;
                background-size: cover;
}

.leftcol {
            width: 350px;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;

}

.rightcol {
            width: 850px;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;

}

.footer {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;     
}
```

Also I have noticed that footer is acting wierd to, it's in the middle of the page in 'rightcol' element.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cramb5fg/1/

Comment: I believe setting the background to 100% only makes it 100% of the size of the viewport, so when your page exceeds the dimensions of the viewport(overflow) the background cuts off when you scroll. Pretty sure someone posted a solution to this problem on SO...

Comment: Note, you can't use body html markup in Fiddle...  it already wraps the html in a body tag, which is why the fiddle is inaccurate.   You may want to re-build with using a div class as a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

See if this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/r47hvdt3/) gets you closer. It has a full screen background too.

It fixes a few errors like:

1. Clearing your floated column divs by adding a "Clearfix" to the container that now holds only the 2 column divs.
2. A wrapper that displays at 100% height and width was added to contain the header, main content, and footer. It also has the main background applied.
3. The float was removed from the footer, and now the footer is absolutely positioned at the bottom, in relation to the main wrapper.
4. The empty `<div class="header"></div>` was removed.

HTML Structure in the JSFiddle Example (based on your wireframe)

```
<div id="main-wrapper">

<div class="navigation">
<nav>
<h1><i class="fa fa-car">Title</i></h1>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="container clearfix">    
<div class="leftcol">
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="sidebar-head">Title</div>
<div class="sidebar-body"><p>...</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="rightcol"><p>...</p></div>
</div> <!-- end container clearfix -->

<div class="footer">Copyright © 2014</div>

</div> <!-- end main-wrapper -->
```

Give this wireframe a good test because some details may have been overlooked, also test by enlarging and reducing the browser area, and holding down CTRL+ or - to to enlarge and shrink the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but your example code is different than your fiddle. You should be able to make your background 100% easily.

```
html {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/400) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/skube/ytawjm7z/)

Also, check out http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ for more info

edit: I've updated your [fiddle with what I think you are trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/skube/cramb5fg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS heigh will if you define position absolute/fixed. such:

```
.class_name{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

One more important matter: top and left also compulsory.

Comment: do u checked by my sollution.?